# Render angular2 Component on ASP.NET 5 MVC view with Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC application that has several views that are serviced by a single Controller. The path of one of them is 'home/settings' and looks like this [image]

With Angular2, I created a UserProfileComponent that basically renders a table containing list of the existing users and I would like it to render below User Profiles in the screenshot above:

*user-profiles.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from "../../services/userService";

@Component({
selector: 'user-profiles',
providers: [UserService],
template: `
    ...
`
})
export class UserProfilesComponent {
    constructor(userService: UserService) {
    userService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(
        users => this.users = users,
        error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
        () => console.log('Completedsfsdf!')
        );
    }
    users = [];
 }
```

Using Routing, I managed to render the UserProfileComponent when the settings view is rendered, but it only renders inside the tag  inside the AppComponent template and I would like it to render inside my  selector inside the settings view. It is also worth noting that the AppComponent is currently rendering inside the _Layout

*app.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './services/userService';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [UserService],
    template: `    
     <p>Angular 2 is running...</p>
     <!-- Routed views go here -->
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `

 })
 export class AppComponent {

 }
```

Which causes the table to render only at a layout level (on top of the page) instead on the  inside the settings view.

*boot.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';
import { UserProfilesComponent } from './components/settings/user-      profiles.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {UserService} from './services/userService'
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home/settings',
        component: UserProfilesComponent
    },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent,  HomeComponent, UserProfilesComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My initial approach here is have each section within the settings view to have its own component, so ideally RecordRollover will have its own component and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Single Page Application (SPA)?  Or are your routes hard-coded on the server with asp.net mvc (and each route re-loads the entire angular application on each view)?

Comment: routes are indeed hardcoded and the browser is reloaded on each route.

Comment: You have created big mess here with routes managed on the server and you are attempting to do routes on the client with angular.  There are circumstances where it can be justifiable to create multiple "spa silos" within on asp.net mvc app, but I highly doubt your use case meets such a threshold.   Here is the way, in my opinion, you should structure your project:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40234393/3532945